# Шаблон лайтбокса

Tags: javascript, jquery, шаблоны

Мне нужно создать подобное портфолио, как тут http://smolsound.ru/#view (чтобы при нажатии на фото открывалась галерея). Я еще новичок, помогите, пожалуйста. Может у кого-нибудь есть примерно похожие шаблоны? или может кто-то просто сможет мне помочь советом? не могу разобраться с кодом.

Comment: для начала покажите что  у вас есть...и конкретизируйте что именно у вас не получается!

Comment: Посмотрите на исходники fancybox или magnificPopup